# Optimal Custom Operator with Generic Type Constraint for Numerical Type

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I'm implementing (for an article) two custom infix operators:

- ¿% - To calculate percent of total.
- %? - To calculate the percent that represents a segment of total.

After debugging some errors and looking for information I finally found a way to get my code working:

```
protocol NumericType {
    static func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Int) -> Self
    static func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Int) -> Self
} // NumericType

extension Double : NumericType {
    internal static func *(lhs: Double, rhs: Int) -> Double {
        return lhs * Double(rhs)
    }

    internal static func /(lhs: Double, rhs: Int) -> Double {
        return lhs / Double(rhs)
    }
 }

extension Float  : NumericType {
    internal static func *(lhs: Float, rhs: Int) -> Float {
        return lhs * Float(rhs)
    }

    internal static func /(lhs: Float, rhs: Int) -> Float {
        return lhs / Float(rhs)
    }
 }

extension Int : NumericType { }

infix operator ¿%

func ¿% <T: NumericType>(percentage: T, ofThisTotalValue: T) -> T {

    return (percentage * ofThisTotalValue) / 100

} // infix operator ¿%

infix operator %?

func %? <T: NumericType>(segmentOf: T, thisTotalValue: T) -> T {

    return (segmentOf * 100) / thisTotalValue

} // infix operator %?

let percentage: Double = 8
let price: Double = 45

let save = percentage ¿% price

print("\(percentage) % of \(price) $ = \(save) $")

print("\(save) $ of \(price) $ = \(save %? price) %")
```

...the output:

```
8.0 % of 45.0 $ = 3.6 $
3.6 $ of 45.0 $ = 8.0 %
```

My question is the following:

Do you thinks there could be a more optimal and readable approach?

Yes? Could you give some advice or share an example?

Comment: It seems that your code is working as expected. If you are looking for a review and suggestions for possible improvements, post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I will do it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm a little skeptical of using a custom operator for this. 
*Personally* I'd rather just have a functions that do this calculation:

```
func percent(of partial: Double, from amount: Double) -> Double {
    return partial / amount * 100
}

percent(of: 50, from: 100)
// -> 50
```

I feel like that's going to be a lot easier in long (and short) term for readability and maintainability.

Having said that... If you do really want to create these custom operators here's how I'd approach it.

You were on the right path! you would have gotten the error:

> binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NumericType' and 'Double'

And you went down the path of implementing functions so that the * and / operators can be used on types `NumericType` and `Double`.

But actually, rather than redefining signatures for * and / to work on new types, it's going to be a lot easier to find a way to get a double value from your generic type and use that in the calculation.

Here's how it might look:

```
protocol NumericType {
    var doubleValue: Double { get }
}

infix operator ¿%
infix operator %?

func ¿% <T: NumericType>(percentage: T, ofTotal: Double) -> Double {
    return percentage.doubleValue * ofTotal / 100.0
}

func %? <T: NumericType>(segment: T, ofTotal: Double) -> Double {
    return segment.doubleValue * 100 / ofTotal
}

extension Double: NumericType {
    var doubleValue: Double { return self }
}

extension Int: NumericType {
    var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) }
}
```

Hope this helps, and please please please reconsider using a standard function instead of these custom operators!