# How to implement a default method for a custom infix operator in a protocol extension

Tags: swift, extension-methods, swift-protocols, infix-operator

I'm trying to implement a custom comparison infix operator `==^` as a slimmed down version of the standard equality operator `==`

My app is mostly protocol oriented and therefor I'm trying to implement the default method `static func ==^` inside the protocol extension. However when I make my class conform to the protocol I'm getting a `Type 'MySourceNode' does not conform to protocol 'SourceNodeType'` error and Xcode offers me to add the `static func ==^` protocol stub.

My question is, how do I properly write the default implementation inside the protocol extension?

I've tried to find answers on SO but most of them are older and only talk about generic methods that are defined outside the protocol extension. But that doesn't seem to work in my case.

Here is a playground file with a simplified version of my protocol. There is a bit of background info after the code. If something is unclear please let me know in the comments and I'll update my question accordingly.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

infix operator ==^: ComparisonPrecedence

protocol SourceNodeType: SKShapeNode {

    var constrainZRotation: SKConstraint! { get set }
    func setConstraints()

    static func ==^ (lhs: SourceNodeType, rhs: SourceNodeType) -> Bool

}

extension SourceNodeType {

    func setConstraints() {
        print("Setting constraints")
    }

    static func ==^ (lhs: SourceNodeType, rhs: SourceNodeType) -> Bool {
        lhs.frame == rhs.frame &&
            lhs.position == rhs.position &&
            lhs.constrainZRotation == rhs.constrainZRotation
    }
}

class MySourceNode: SKShapeNode, SourceNodeType {

    var constrainZRotation: SKConstraint!

}
```

To explain the reason behind this custom infix operator. I need it because I'm comparing subclasses of SpriteKit's SKShapeNodes with each other quite often. But I don't want every variable in the class like the accessibility label or name to be compared as I'm changing these values when I added the nodes to the scene, which is partially after the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized putting the `func ==^` method outside of the protocol and only implementing it with the `SourceNodeType` protocol as `rhs` and `lhs` types was exactly what I needed!

This answer solved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390111/12764795

Maybe someone could confirm that this is the current and correct way to go?

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

infix operator ==^: ComparisonPrecedence

func ==^ (lhs: SourceNodeType, rhs: SourceNodeType) -> Bool {
    lhs.frame == rhs.frame &&
        lhs.position == rhs.position &&
        lhs.constrainZRotation == rhs.constrainZRotation
}

protocol SourceNodeType: SKShapeNode {
    var constrainZRotation: SKConstraint! { get set }
    func setConstraints()
}

extension SourceNodeType {
    func setConstraints() {
        print("Setting constraints")
    }
}

class MySourceNode: SKShapeNode, SourceNodeType {
    var constrainZRotation: SKConstraint!
}

let lhsSourceNode = MySourceNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
var rhsSourceNode = MySourceNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
print(lhsSourceNode ==^ rhsSourceNode) // TRUE

rhsSourceNode.name = "Name used for testing"
print(lhsSourceNode ==^ rhsSourceNode) // TRUE

rhsSourceNode.position.y += 100

print(lhsSourceNode ==^ rhsSourceNode) // FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you just can't satisfy this kind of protocol requirements :

```
static func ==^ (lhs: SourceNodeType, rhs: SourceNodeType) -> Bool
```

I could not find a clear explanation in [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID46) but if you try to make a type conform to that protocol it won't compile [and it's not supposed to](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/test/decl/func/operator.swift#L277).

> My question is, how do I properly write the default implementation inside the protocol extension?

If you want to use parameters of type `SourceNodeType`, using a free function is the **most straightforward** way but removing the operator requirement silences the compiler error ie :

```
protocol SourceNodeType: SKShapeNode {

    var constrainZRotation: SKConstraint! { get set }
    func setConstraints()
}
```

until you try to use your operator :

```
let node = MySourceNode()
let otherNode = MySourceNode()
node ==^ otherNode // Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred
```

You can still work around this issue by declaring :

```
extension SourceNodeType {
    static func ==^ (lhs: Self, rhs: SourceNodeType) -> Bool {
        lhs.frame == rhs.frame &&
            lhs.position == rhs.position &&
            lhs.constrainZRotation == rhs.constrainZRotation
    }
}
```

it will work as expected but you still will not be able to declaring it as a protocol requirement because it will trigger :

> Protocol 'SourceNodeType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Since rhs is of type `SourceNodeType`.